# How to fix triangle position when printing triangles for Sierpinski method

Tags: java

I'm currently making a code to print out Sierpinski triangles using recursion. I am able to print out the first center triangle for the base case (n==1), and 3 triangles around the base case for n==2, but after that (n==3,4, etc) the triangles orient themselves oddly, and I can't seem to find where the error in the code is that's causing the triangles to orient in that way.

I've tried altering where the Sierpinski() function is called and I've tried several different ways to represent the x and y coordinates (which correspond to the bottom point of the triangle). The height method and filledTriangle method seem to be working fine since the triangles are equilateral and they are correctly filled and being printed. The error seems isolated to the sierpinski method. The base case (n==1) is fine, but the issue is definitely in the else branch of the sierpinski method.

```java
public class Sierpinski {
    // Height of an equilateral triangle whose sides are of the specified length. 
    public static double height(double length) 
    {
        double height = (Math.sqrt(3)/2) * length;

        return height;
    }

    // Draws a filled equilateral triangle whose bottom vertex is (x, y) 
    // of the specified side length. 
    public static void filledTriangle(double x, double y, double length) 
    {
        double[] xArray = {x - height(length)/Math.sqrt(3), x, x + height(length)/Math.sqrt(3)};
        double[] yArray = {y + height(length), y , y + height(length)};

        StdDraw.filledPolygon(xArray,yArray);
    }

    // Draws a Sierpinski triangle of order n, such that the largest filled 
    // triangle has bottom vertex (x, y) and sides of the specified length. 
    static void sierpinski(int n, double x, double y, double length) 
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            filledTriangle(x, y, length);
        }

        else
        {
            filledTriangle(x, y, length);

            //Triangle Up
            sierpinski(n - 1, x, y + height(length), length/2);

            //Triangle Left
            sierpinski(n - 1, x/2, y, length/2);

            //Triangle Right x/2 + .5
            sierpinski(n - 1, x/2 + .5, y, length/2);

        }
    }

    // Takes an integer command-line argument n; 
    // draws the outline of an equilateral triangle (pointed upwards) of length 1; 
    // whose bottom-left vertex is (0, 0) and bottom-right vertex is (1, 0); and 
    // draws a Sierpinski triangle of order n that fits snugly inside the outline. 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        double[] originalX = {0, 0.5, 1};
        double[] originalY = {0, Math.sqrt(3)/2, 0};
        double x = 0.5;
        double y = 0;
        double length = 0.5;
        StdDraw.polygon(originalX, originalY);

        sierpinski(n, x, y, length);


    }
}
```

I get the results I expect for n == 1 and n == 2, but after that I get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't exactly sure what graphics library you were using so I converted to Swing. But essentially this works by painting recursively until it gets below a certain size. The position of each triangle is calculated with standard trig.

```
public class Tri extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sierpinkski");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new Tri(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Tri() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        paintTriangle(gr, 500, 500, 400);
    }

    private void paintTriangle(Graphics2D gr, float x, float y, float size) {
        if (size > .5) {
            float vert = (float) (size * Math.sin(Math.PI / 6));
            float horz = (float) (size * (float) Math.cos(Math.PI / 6));
            Path2D.Float path = new Path2D.Float();
            path.moveTo(x, y - size);
            path.lineTo(x + horz, y + vert);
            path.lineTo(x - horz, y + vert);
            path.closePath();
            gr.draw(path);
            paintTriangle(gr, x, y - size / 2, size / 2);
            paintTriangle(gr, x + horz / 2, y + vert / 2, size / 2);
            paintTriangle(gr, x - horz / 2, y + vert / 2, size / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using the StdDraw library. I appreciate the help, but this is a completely different solution. I'm trying to find out why my code works for n == 1 and n == 2, but n == 3,4... it doesn't.